# Как реализовать просмотр сайта в изображение монитора на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть изображение монитора на странице сайта и нужно в нем реализовать просмотр миниатюры другого сайта, с кнопками вниз и вверх для скроллинга этого сайта. Возможно ли реализовать такое?

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать фрейм внутри дива с overflow: hidden и сам фрейм не сроллить, а поднимать вверх изменением top, тем самым создавая иллюзию скроллинга

Answer (score -1):

Миниатюру другого сайта можно вставить с помощью iframe, но доступ из JS к сайту на другом домене в iframe вы получить не можете по соображениям безопасности. Так что скроллить по кнопке у вас не получится.

```html
<iframe width=300 height=200 src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp"></iframe>
```